# JSON parsing unexpectedly passing when sending POST to REST service

Tags: json, rest, jpa, spring-boot

I have built a REST service using Spring-Boot. Everything works fine. However, when I update my `curl` command to POST erroneous names for my POJO variables, I get an object with default values.

My entity looks like:

```
@Entity
public class UserTask {

    @Id
    private Long userId;
    private int numComplete;
    private int numIncomplete;

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public int getNumComplete() {
        return numComplete;
    }

    public void setNumComplete(int numComplete) {
        this.numComplete = numComplete;
    }

    public int getNumIncomplete() {
        return numIncomplete;
    }

    public void setNumIncomplete(int numIncomplete) {
        this.numIncomplete = numIncomplete;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder("[id : ").append(getUserId())
                .append(", complete : ").append(getNumComplete())
                .append(", incomplete : ").append(getNumIncomplete())
                .append("]").toString();
    }

}
```

I execute a POST against my service like so:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{ \"uId\" : \"1\", \"numC\" : \"3\", \"numI\" : \"2\" }" http://localhost:8080/user-task
```

The returned status for the `POST` is `201` and the record is written (in this case updated) in the database. When I debug, I see that the `UserTask` instance passed into the REST controller method has default value `null` for `userId`, `0` for `numComplete` and `0` for `numIncomplete`. I thought that the JSON parser would've failed when it couldn't unmarshal the POST JSON content as a `UserTask` instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JSONSchema to validate the @RequestBody or @Valid of Hibernate Validator, so if the POJO doesn't met this validations you could Thrown a Exception of RequiredParameters for example.

```
yourMethod(@RequestBody @Valid UserTask)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try and report back.

Comment: Take a look to this example https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-rest-api-validation/